# XAMPP: htdocs folder permissions for Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, linux, laravel, xampp

Usually I use `chmod -R 755` for the `htdocs` folder.

But if I'm executing `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel applicationname` and call http://localhost/applicationname/public/ I get this error.

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/applicationname/storage/logs/laravel-2019-09-12.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I executed `chmod -R 755 applicationname` in the `htdocs` folder because I thought the newly created folders may have different permissions but I get the same error. I have to use `chmod -R 777 applicationname` to make it work. Weirdly when I use `chmod -R 755 applicationname` afterwards I don't get the error. I have no idea what's going on.

What permissions should I give to the folder and subfolders to avoid such issues in the future?

The question has been answered for a common webserver but not for XAMPP. If I follow the instructions I get the same problems as I stated above. I have to use `chmod -R 777 storage/*` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*`

Maybe after that you will need to clear cache

`php artisan config:cache`